# Garage face stem wall

Tags: structural-engineering

We are building a house and it has come to our attention that the stem wall on the face of the brick veneer garage between a double garage door and a single garage door was poured at only 4 inches thick, but the studs above are 2X6. The builder built it up by hand after the fact with a separate concrete substance.  The brick mortar outside above the two garage doors is already starting to show some step cracking involving about 5 courses of brick all the way to the roof line. There is also a vertical crack in the brick just below the lintel on the double garage door. How concerning is this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If your brick veneer is thin it doesn't need a foundation per se. It is attached by fasteners to its backing board (substrate).

But if the brick is a tick brick veneer, you can shore up the wall and cut and remove the foundation stem wall in approximately 18" lengths, and pour a 6" thick stem with a dowel on the sides to adjacent concrete.

[image: brick veneer]

Answer (score 0):

The cracks you described are the classical deformation crack caused by either the deflection of the lintel or the deformation of the head of the door frames. I suggest checking the levelness of the wall above the garage doors, also, checking the plumpness of the jambs, which could have deformed.

The cracks wouldn't magically close up themselves, and can only be getting worse. I think you need a structural inspection to determine the true cause and extent of the damages.